# Outlook 2013 not syncing calendar

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, iphone, calendar, ios

I have an issue on Outlook 2013 on my desktop Windows 10.
My Calendar works on my Outlook 2013, but it does not
sync with my calendar on my Outlook app on my iPhone.

I have updated
iPhone to ios 14.2. I confirmed in the Settings that
Outlook app is syncing with the calendar. I confirmed
that my correct Outlook account is signed in the Settings,
and the password worked correctly there.

On the desktop Windows 10, I noticed that in the Outlook
2013 Calendar section, in the center left, it says my Calendar
is on "This Computer Only". I do not want it to be only
on that computer, I want any changes I make on my Outlook 2013
to copy to my iPhone Outlook app. I do not know how to change
that. In the Outlook 2013 backstage settings, it is currently
set up as IMAP, without any of the Microsoft Exchanges types.

How can I fix this, and how can I help any of you nice techs
gain additional information into this issue? I am happy to
be of help here, if someone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar [thread](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/157275/outlook-2013-calendar-not-syncing.html?childToView=157603#answer-157603) in Microsoft QA forum, as Jeff Yang mentioned, it's by design and we couldn't change it. As an alternative, it's suggested to use Exchange account or Outlook.com account, which could sync more items(including calendars) to server.

Comment: I created that thread that you linked me to. That is why the text is the same. Did you think of that?

Comment: Okay,  as a suggestion for your requirment, you could try to use icloud or other tools to sync your calendar between your iPhone and Outlook for windows, for more information, you could refer to this thread:https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_imobile-mso_o365b/how-do-i-sync-iphone-calendar-with-outlook-app/4474286f-321b-4a4f-9818-18591e17aaf6.

Comment: DavidPostill, prove to me there is an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't sync calendars with IMAP accounts.

[Here's](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sync-basics-what-you-can-and-cannot-sync-5537d587-4930-4ac2-b044-3568509b1294) a Microsoft Support page that details what you can and can't sync with the available email methods.

Comment: Thank you, that link to the Microsoft page clearly listing the features or lack of features was extremely helpful. I have found the various forums here and on Microsoft.com to be far more helpful than the Official Microsoft Agents, odd.

     What are the specifications to use for an Exchange account on Outlook? What are all of the steps to use to safely transition from IMAP to Exchange? I have tried to find this information, but I can't find it.

Comment: Update: I read on LifeWire that Google Exchange ActiveSync no longer works on personal or free Google accounts, is this true? Is there any further information out there to confirm this?